# Android widget. Mock view before widget loads

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a simple widget on the homescreen. It successfully loads after phone restarts but it takes some time and during this period (~5-10 sec) there is no views where widgets have to be.

I've tried some other widgets and they load some mock emty views just after  device loaded.

How can I show some views just after devices have been loaded?

Some screens.

Just after reboot.

[image]

And after some time.

[image]

I've tested callbacks that my provider receives:

```
10-27 21:11:29.486    onEnabled
10-27 21:11:29.496    onReceive
10-27 21:11:29.506    onUpdate
```

So they happens almost at the same time.

Maybe there is some (maybe layout) attribute as "widgetViewBeforLoaded" or smth else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out the problem.

Initialy widget load only layout of your widget and not fill any info into it.

My widget layout was:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgetText"
    style="@style/widget_text"/>
```

And in this case there is no text and backgrounds in wigdets, it's possible to define default view for example by changing layout to:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"/> <!-- DEFAULT BG !-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgetText"
    style="@style/widget_text"
    android:text="Loading..."/> <!-- DEFAULT TEXT !-->
```